# Click event callback gets called the second time the user clicks on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
$('#search-form').on('keyup change paste', function(event) {
  $('#songs').empty();
  $('#aplayer').css('display', 'none');

  var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
  if (keyword.trim() === '') {
    return;
  }

  const relatedSongs = songs.filter(function(song) {
    return song.name.includes(keyword);
  });
  $('#songs').append(relatedSongs.map(function(song) {
    return '<li class="list-group-item" data-index="' + song.index + '"><a href="#" class="song-name">name：' + song.name + '</a></li>';
  }));
});

$('#songs').on('click', '.song-name', function() {
  const index = $(this).parent().data('index');
  const song = songs[index];
  ap.list.clear();
  ap.list.add(song);
  $('#aplayer').css('display', 'block');
});
```

The point is `$('#songs').append`, I dynamically create elements and append them into the #songs element.

All dynamically created elements have a link of class `song-name`, and you can notice I bind a click event callback on them.

The problem is: 
When user clicks the link first time, the callback does not get called. The callback will be called only when the user clicks on it one more time.

I can't understand why is it happened? Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any fiddle if possible ?

Comment: Share your HTML also

Comment: on #search-form input when you press key two events fire one is keyup and second is change. so two time eventHandler calls.

Comment: Not your issue, but a design / efficiency note: Since in the click event you just go away to get the parent() and its song-index before you can do anything, why not remove the `<a` entirely and just print the song title directly in the `<li` and make the `<li` the clickable element. Then you don't need to traverse the DOM to get the index value and you have less HTML. You can always style the `li` to look like a hyperlink. Or alternatively just put the index value on the hyperlink, again removing the need for the .parent() search

Comment: I mocked this at http://jsfiddle.net/0j15ruz9/7/ (some assumptions about the HTML but it's not hard to figure out). Ashish is right that the "keyup / change / paste" handler can fire too many times - it's a bit inefficient, might be bad if the songs array is big, but I see no evidence of the "only works on the second click" song issue - see the console logs to know when the event is firing

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your demo code, but this problem is also occurred on your code. If I enter 'a', the 'name：Aaa' appends to the list. If I click on this link immediately, click event callback will not be called. It will be called only when I click on it one more time, and now 'Aplayer element' is displayed.

Comment: @ADyson But what suprises me is when I test it on my phone, it has no this problem. But when I test it on my MacBook Air, this problem happened.

Comment: it has to do with the keyup handler. Check my answer

Comment: @user3087000 "On my macbook air"...the operation of JavaScript is not affected by the operating system, it's affected by the browser it runs in. The same browser can often run on different operating systems. Operating systems can run many different browsers. So please state the _browser_ and also the _browser version number_ instead. Give an example of (at least) one where the code works correctly, and one where you experience the error. Test my JSFIddle in that same browser and see if you have the error in there too, to be sure it's not just something else in your code.

Comment: @user3087000 FYI I tested the Fiddle in Chrome 67 (desktop version) and did not experience the problem you stated

Comment: @ADyson Just as @Anastasios Selmanis said, when I click the link first time, `#search-form`'s 'keyup' event handler gets called, but `.song-name`'s click event handler is not called. It only gets called when I click it the second time. And this problem is happened on your code too.

Comment: @ADyson I tested it on Chrome 67 too.

Comment: @user3087000 Ok sorry, I had not actually tested it properly because coincidentally I was alt-tabbing to a separate console window to watch it, and this caused the textbox's change event to fire, but by the time I tabbed back and clicked on the element it had re-generated the song list and I could click the songs successfully. I finally put the console side-by-side so I could see it without that, and discovered the reason for the problem, it occurs when you click straight on a song when the textbox was the last focused element - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because when you click on a song, you simultaneously lose the focus on the text box. This fires the "change" event of the textbox, which then clears the song list, so the song element you just clicked on no longer exists, and this occurs before its "click" handler has chance to execute.

Of course the song is instantly replaced by one which looks identical, giving you an optical illusion which might lead you to believe you're still looking at the same HTML element, when actually it's just a twin.

In my opinion the best option here is simply to remove the "change" event from the list of handled events - it's superfluous because keyup and/or paste already fire before it whenever any text is entered. So your search event handler will become:

```
$('#search-form').on('keyup paste', function(event) {
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/0j15ruz9/26/ for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the keyup event from your initial handler. The change event will cover the cases you need and it will work correctly on first click.

On your first click the first event handler is triggered first and something gets messed.

Answer (score -1):

I was suffer the same issue several times, I don't know what is the reason of that (I supose that it happeng for something related to the DOM's actualization), but I resolve it that way

```
function song_name_click(e){
    const index = $(this).parent().data('index');
    const song = songs[index];
    ap.list.clear();
    ap.list.add(song);
    $('#aplayer').css('display', 'block');
}

...
$('#songs').append(relatedSongs.map(function(song) {
    return '<li class="list-group-item" data-index="' + song.index + '"><a href="#" class="song-name">name：' + song.name + '</a></li>';
}));
$(".song-name").off('click');
$(".song-name").on('click', song_name_click);
...
```

Comment: this won't work because `$(".song-name").on('click', song_name_click);` won't ever bind- those elements don't exist when this code runs. The original delegated syntax in the question is correct. That is not the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but you already append the element so, it exists in the moment of the binding

Comment: It's not clear from your example. What is in the spaces marked `...`? If you've moved the place where the binding happens, you need to make that explicit, because it's different from the original, and has a direct bearing on the functionality. However, if you run my JSFiddle, linked in the main comments of the question, you'll see it demonstrated that the method of event binding is not an issue. In fact it's impossible to reproduce the stated problem at all.

Comment: I know that the binding method is not the problem, if it was be the problem, the event never trigger. I just saying that I was suffer the same isue and I put a method that i used for resolve it, if you have a better solution please put it as an answer, I will be pleased to read it and use it in my next project.

Comment: "I know that the binding method is not the problem"...then why did you change it (and without explanation)? If it ain't broke, don't fix it, as the saying goes. And "this worked for me so it might work for your situation" is not a million miles from "cargo-cult" programming - i.e. copying some code without fully understanding what it does because it once worked in situation which was (or at least may have been) similar.